# Replace string \ with / android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, replace, replaceall

I need to replace the string "\" with "/"
I tried

> myString.replace("\","/");

but it's kind of syntax it says

> String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote

how can i do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape back slash like:

```
myString.replace("\\","/");
```

Comment: Try to close question if it had answered before :)